# 500th Anniversary of the Protestant Reformation – Bounty Challenge

Tags: discussion, bounty

For several years, Christianity Stack Exchange has done a bounty challenge during the season of Advent (for instance, [in 2016](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6142/16688)) to encourage and reward high-quality answers. Given that October 31st, 2017 is recognized as the 500th Anniversary of the [Protestant Reformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reformation#Early_Reformation_in_Germany), a significant event in Christian history, I'd like to propose that we do a similar bounty challenge for the month of October.

### How it works

If you want to award bounties, add a post to this question to let everybody know. You can choose to award them for whatever criteria you want. Some things that users have done during previous bounty challenges include:

- Reward answers that have not gotten enough attention
- Announce that they will reward answers on certain topics
- Give bounties however you feel like

Given the occasion for the bounty challenge, **it is strongly recommended that bounties be awarded for answers related to the Protestant Reformation or Protestantism itself.**

You can award one bounty over the whole challenge, one a week, or any other frequency you choose.

If you do choose to award a bounty, please update your answer on this post to let others know about your participation.

Now go out and write good questions and answers worth of bounties!

> “If you want to change the world, pick up your pen and write.”
>
> ― Martin Luther

Comment: NB: Special search parameters can be used to find recent questions and answers on a particular tag, like this: `[church-history] created:1m.. score:0..`  Just replace "church-history" with the tag of your choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a lot of bounty to give, but I'll happily award bounties as part of this challenge!

Given Martin Luther's importance as the founder of the Reformation (and of modern Lutheranism), I plan to reward excellent answers on questions related to Martin Luther himself, <s>to a maximum of one per week</s> as often as I feel like it.

I may also decide to give out bounties about other topics related to the Reformation that I think are exemplary and/or need more attention.

### Bounties awarded

- [Matt Gutting’s answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60202/16688) on [Did Martin Luther express his views on suicide?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60197/16688)
- [Davidlol’s answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60206/16688) on [Did Luther ever acknowledge that his Catechism would require textual changes as language evolves?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60200/16688)
- [Zenon’s answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60378/16688) on [Were there indulgences sold for those who had no family when they died?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60370/16688)
- [Nigel J’s answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60494/16688) on [Why did Luther not support iconoclasm like some other reformers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60484/16688)
- [Zenon's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60490/16688) on [Were celebrations for the 400th Anniversary of the Reformation held in Germany during World War I?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60483/16688)
- [Davidlol's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60525/16688) on [Why did Katarina von Bora need to hide in a barrel to escape from her convent?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60515/16688)

Given the reason we are celebrating this anniversary, I gave a larger bounty for

- [Davidlol's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60555/16688) on [Did Martin Luther really nail his 95 Theses to the church door?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60503/16688)