# If I give away reputation using bounties, can I lose access to a privilege if I end up below the required reputation for that privilege?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, privileges

Let's say I reach 20 thousand reputation (giving me more things that I can do), and then bounty away 100 reputation. Will I lose my newly gained privileges?

Comment: Related (note the mention of losing access to a privilege in the body of the post): [Is it OK if I give away lots of reputation in bounties?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3280/54880)

Comment: @V2Blast I saw that post! I missed the part on losing privileges though, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if your rep drops, you lose the privileges.

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges. - [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)